# Deserialize nested Kotlin object in springMVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

I'm trying to deserialize a complex GET request into a structure of nested objects.

The GET requests looks like:

```
curl 'localhost:8080/?id=1&inner.id=1'
```

and the code should look like this:

```kotlin
class RootObj(val id: Int, inner: InnerObject)
class InnerObject(val id: Int)

@RestController
class SearchController {

    @GetMapping(path = ["/"])
    fun getRoot(rootObj: RootObj): String {
        return "ok"
    }
}
```

This doesn't work out of the box I guess because spring doesn't know how properly create this nested structure.

```
Parameter specified as non-null is null: [...] parameter inner","path":"/"}%
```

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Maybe providing a totally custom deserializer code?

As alternative solution, I guess I could flatten the object hierarchy but for doing so I must be able to map a query parameter like `inner.id` to a field named `innerId`

Answer (score 2):

Spring can actually map the query params to the custom object directly, but you need to provide defaults to the params of the custom object constructor.

So you need to define your classes as below for it to work

```
class RootObj(val id: Int = 0, val inner: InnerObject = InnerObject(0))
class InnerObject(var id: Int = 0)
```

Do note that the `id` field of `InnerObject` would have to be declared as `var` for Spring to be able to map it. Then `curl 'localhost:8080/?id=1&inner.id=1'` would work fine.

Comment: thanks, default parameters are a good suggestion. Sure it would be better to been able to keep the correct immutability of the parameters...